# AngularJS: $sce.trustAsHtml returns code as text

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

So basically I have JSON array that returns data, one element is actual HTML code, I have problem when I use that in ng-repeat, here are the codes:
JSON:

```
[
    {
    "id": "43",
    "name": "Name",
    "html": "&lt;div style=&quot;text-align:justify&quot;&gt;&lt;div style=&quot;text-align:center&quot;&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Stuff&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;br /&gt;for stuff&amp;nbsp;&lt;br /&gt;and stuff&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;",
    "date": "2016-01-02"

    }
]
```

Html:

```
<md-content ng-repeat="thing in stuff">
    <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom>
        <md-tab label="Basic">
            <md-content class="md-padding">
                <h4 ng-show="thing.id">ID:</h4>
                <div ng-show="thing.id">{{thing.id}}</div>
                <h4 ng-show="thing.name">Name:</h4>
                <div ng-show="thing.name">{{thing.name}}</div>
            </md-content>
        </md-tab>
        <md-tab label="Advanced">
            <md-content class="md-padding">
                <div ng-bind-html="trustHtml(thing.html)"></div>
            </md-content>
        </md-tab>
    </md-tabs>
</md-content>
```

In the controler I have `$scope.trustHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml;` to decode html from JSON and it should render it. But it outputs decode HTML as text, as in:

[Acutal render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXngJ.png)

I tried adding as filter:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .filter('asHtml', ['$sce', function($sce){
        return function(text) {
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
        };
    }]);
```

I tried adding it as directive:

```
myApp.directive('dynamic', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.dynamic, function(html) {
                ele.html(html);
                $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
            });
        }
    };
})
```

But everytime I only get html as text, and nothing more...

Comment: That would be because your JSON already has escaped HTML. Surely you want the string in the JSON to be `"<div style=..." ` instead of `&lt;div...`

Answer (score 0):

your `$scope.trustHtml` function should be like this.

```
angular.module("test",['ngSanitize'])
.controller("testCtrl",['$scope','$sce',function($scope,$sce){

  $scope.trustHtml  =   function(html){
                        return $sce.trustAsHtml(html);;
                      }
}
```

Please check here for [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31231648/angularjs-ng-bind-html-html-input-part-missing)

Comment: have you included ng-sanitize?

Comment: Yes, linked and included in module creation.

Comment: Please check console

Comment: Nothing there, I console.log(thing.html) it returns the html code, so it's working on that end, no errors nor warnings.